# Unit tests: Testing inner Promise

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, es6-promise

I've been searching the web for a while and I've yet to find the answer to this.

Let's say we're testing the following:

```
function p() {
    return Promise.resolve(1);
}

class Sample {
    constructor() {
        this.stuff = 2;
    }

    sample () {
        p().then((data) => {
            this.stuff = data;
        });

        //more stuff
    }
}

module.exports = {Sample};
```

How could we check that, eventually `this.stuff` is populated without returning said promise?

This is what I've been able to do until now:

```
let expect = require('chai').expect;
let sinon = require('sinon');

let Sample = require('./source.js').Sample;

describe('stuff', function () {
    it('test2', function() {
        let sample = new Sample();

        return Promise.resolve(sample.sample())
            .then(() => {
                expect(sample.stuff).to.be.eql(2);
            });
    });
});
```

In which, each `then` gets the next tick (if we had multiple `then`s in our sample we'd also need multiple `then`s in our test).

(And before you say `process.nextTick`, I want this to run in the browser with karma-mocha)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you looked at chai-as-promised?

Comment: @kenhowardpdx I did, but if I understood it correctly it would only work if I had the inner promise. But, reading the chai-as-promised's documentation might have given me an idea.

Answer (score 0):

This could be easily tested if the code was restructured, to support testability.

One way to do this would be to take an optional `p` interface for the object instantiation.  The value could default to your defined `p` but would allow for a test to create a fake object and verify that your `Sample` operates on it correctly.

```
function p() {
    return Promise.resolve(1);
}

class Sample {
    constructor(pFn) {
        this.stuff = 2;
        this.p = pFn || p;
    }

    sample () {
        this.p().then((data) => {
            this.stuff = data;
        });

        //more stuff
    }
}
```

This would allow you to provide a promise-like object, for your unit test, that executes synchronously.

Comment: So you're saying that in the test, I would need to do something like `let sample = new Sample ({then: () => 2});` ? It's a lil bit convoluted but I think it could work (may not really scale in a large-scale project though)

Comment: @Atekon yes the test would be responsible (and able) to configure whatever type of object it needed to verify what it needs to.

Comment: ```
        pMock = function () {
            return {
                then: function(fn) {
                    return fn(2);
                }
            }
        }

        let sample = new Sample(pMock);`
It does work, but uhmmm it ain't the cleaniest code ever xD

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to periodically check for the set value.

```
it('test2', function(done) {
    let sample = new Sample();
    let assert = function() {
        if(sample.stuff === 2) {
            done();
        } else {
            setTimeout(assert, 0);
        }
    };

    sample.sample();
    assert();
});
```

It's not the prettiest, and won't give the best error message on a failure, but it would work. If `sample.stuff` isn't set to `2` within a couple seconds (I think 3 seconds is the default) then the test will fail because `done()` was not called in time.

---

Another possible option is to have the test replace `stuff` with a setter. Then you can `expect()` on set.

```
it('test2', function(done) {
    let sample = new Sample();
    Object.defineProperty(sample, 'stuff', { set: function (value) {
        expect(value).to.be.eql(2);
        done();
    }});

    sample.sample();
});
```

Comment: Yeah, I guess I could do that, but I was looking for something prettier XD

Comment: @Atekon - understandable. I added a 2nd possible solution. I haven't tried it, but I think it might work. You might need to add a getter too depending on the rest of your code.

Comment: Didn't think of that (it's a great idea), but the setter is never called (as the then is never executed).